# how to add mediation for get token of WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I Have This API And I Used the Message Mediation Below to Authenticate and Get the Token:

curl -X POST "URL" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "username=user&password=password"

result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9acRO.jpg)

```
<payloadFactory media-type="x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <format>
        {
        "username":"user",
        "password":"password"
        }
    </format>
    <args>
        
    </args>
</payloadFactory>

 <header name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="transport" />
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />

<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <http method="POST" uri-template="URL" />
    </endpoint>
</call>


<property name="bearer-token" expression="json-eval($..token)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('resource')" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
<header name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('bearer-token'))" scope="transport" />
<payloadFactory media-type="x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
       <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('request-body')" />
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

But i have this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlRvM.jpg)

WSO2 API Manager Logs

INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = url, HEALTH CHECK URL = url
[2021-07-28 16:22:39,696]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = url, HEALTH CHECK URL = url

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, you have provided the correct token endpoint url for the Call mediator

```
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <http method="POST" uri-template="https://your-token-endpoint/oauth" />
    </endpoint>
</call>
```